# ruby rails 4.1 module - inconsistent error - not initialized "uninitialized constant"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, uninitialized-constant, ruby-2.1

I'm using ruby 2.1.5 and rails 4.1 in the following folder structure:

```
- lib/
  - notifications/
    - notifications.rb
    - group_actions.rb
```

```
# notifications.rb
module Notifications

end
```

```
# group_actions.rb
class GroupActions
  self.do_something
end
```

```
# inside a controller
class Api::V1::PostsController < Api::BaseController
  include Notifications
  .
  .
  .
  def create
    Notifications::GroupActions.do_something
  end
  .
  .
  .
end
```

I also added this line in "config/application.rb" to autoload my module

```
# config/application.rb
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib/notifications)
```

This works perfectly ***SOMETIMES***, and other times breaks and raises error "Uninitialized constant Notifications::GroupActions"

This is inconsistent, it works in a request and raises this error in following!!! ... it might work for days and break for hours and return again working !!!

***I noticed that it always works on the first request after  restarting the server*** if this hint helps.

please help

Comment: What happens if you use `::Notifications::GroupActions.do_something` instead?

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but just a wild guess.
You're including Notifications module (in this specific code - notifications module has no method group_actions)

What I see is that You use scope of Notifications::GroupActions.do_something.

---

Guess 1:
Inside controller also include GroupActions

---

Guess 2:
Inside Notofications module add another module

```
module Notifications
  module GroupActions
    def self.do_something
```

---

Guess 3:

Try to inherit.

```
module Notifications < GroupActions
```

or

```
module GroupActions < Notifications
```

---

Hope that any of these solutions will help.

If not, sorry :)